# How to change reference to local ( from GAC to bin )

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I've got MS Chart control and with a references to GAC.
I found them ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies )

but how to change GAC to local copy (bin) for comparability with other servers without installed MS Chart control for VS .

I've tried to add dll files manually but that was a fail.
It's looking like I need to config Web.Config manually.

change it

```
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies>
```

somehow to move it from GAC to bin , so How ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Solution Explorer in Visual Studio (or VWD, if you use the express version), find the DLL under References. Right-click it, and select Properties. Change **Copy Local** to **True**.

If you have a Web Site Project instead of a Web Application Project, the references will be directly in the Bin folder.

Comment: but there is no right click menu in WebSite options. It's not Web Application project.

Comment: @nCdy How did you 'add dll files manually' if you didn't right click and choose 'Add Reference'?

Comment: @Jeaffrey Gilbert Drug and drop ... but that wont helps. btw add reference if I pick a files returns GAC reference ... no idea why. (offtop: Jeaffrey is really beauty name)

Comment: @nCdy Thx. Right click then on the dll inside Reference, click properties, and change `Copy Local` to `True` as @Tomas said.

Comment: There are only File name and Path properties. maybe it's because I'm using Nemerle integration :( So I'll try just move to bin those dll files... Hope it be fine on other PC.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the DLL in your solution (Solution items).

Create a .refresh file in your BIN folder that points to your copied DLL, preferable using relative paths.

Add the .refresh file to your project (in the BIN folder).

Remove any references to the assembly from the web.config file.

Dave.